# How to get the count and values of item in a subcategory with parent_id in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, eloquent

How do I get the count and values of all items within a subcategory that has a parent_id. I have a category model which is related to the product model. And in the category table, there are parent_ids and their subcategories. How do I return all the products belonging to a parent category?

The database is shown below
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjMia.png)

The Relationships are shown here

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Then in my controller, this returns 0 as count

```php
public function niche($url)
{
    $niche = Category::where('url',$url)->first();

    $categories = Category::where('parent_id',$niche->id)->get();
    $products = [];

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $products = Product::where('category_id',$category->id)->get();
    }

    dd($products->count());
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVcUq.png)

Please how do I get the number of products belonging to this niche?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `products()` is a relationship method of products and categories

Can you try like this:

```
$products = [];

foreach($categories as $category){
    array_push($products, $category->products());
}

dd(count($products, true));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks. This returned the count of  each subcategories inside the niche. How do I get and display all the products inside the main category/niche and how can I paginate the output  in blade

Comment: Do you need paginate and count of results ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because every time you go through a loop you create a new product variable, thus it will always dump out the count of the last category in the loop.

You should try something like this:

```
public function niche($url){
$niche = Category::where('url',$url)->first();


$categories = Category::where('parent_id',$niche->id)->get();
$products = [];


foreach($categories as $category){
    array_push($products,$category->products());    
}

dd($products->count());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This returned the count of  each subcategories inside the niche. How do I get and display all the products inside the main category/niche and how can I paginate the output  in blade?

Comment: You should create a new thread about this next time. Also laravel gives a unique paginate() method. Do it like this $products->paginate(5). This will give you 5 products. And you display it in the views by using {{!! $product->render !!}} . Don't forget to pass the variable r products to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result is 0 maybe because the last sub category doesn't have any product.

Btw, I suggest a bit cleaner approach in this base. Lets define a sub categories relationship for a category.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

So you are able to access the products and the number of products in a number of ways:

```
// You can eager load for performance.
$category = Category::with('subCategories.products')->where('url', $url)->first();

$products = $category->subCategories->flatMap->products;
$count = $products->count();

// Or you can eager load JUST the number of products.
$category = Category::withCount('subCategories.products')->where('url', $url)->first();
$numberOfProducts = $category->products_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use withCount on children relationship.

```
$categories = Category::whereNULL('parent_id')->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
            $query->withCount('products');
        }])->get();
```

Hopefully should be work